# Any idea what happened to the Ceiling and how to fix it

Tags: ceiling, paint, popcorn

How would I repair the crack and bulge in the popcorn ceiling? There is additional cracking in the wall nearby. The ceiling was painted 3 years ago and the wall by the ceiling had crack repairs and was repainted also. Here is pic[image]

Comment: Start by fixing the (probable) leak in the roof...

Comment: I'd think the first thing to do, rather than worry about hw to patch it, is find out why the wall is moving in the first place. That's a lot of shift in just 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a minor problem, caused perhaps by small one-time shift in the foundation, or a major problem, due to ongoing soil movements, poor framing etc... This does not look like it's just a poor corner taping job.

Ideally you'd **have a carpenter, framer or engineer check out the framing and foundation of the house**. Sometimes the cause subsides on its own and the damage can be patched, but other times intervention is needed to avoid further and more severe damage.

What matters are age of house, type and quality of construction, soil movement, any water/ice ingress, and even wind after a clear-cut.

If possible, also check with neighbours on the same soil and with the same builder.

To inspect it structurally, have a look around the house to find other hints at movement: other cracked walls, cracked foundation, roof line, doors/windows under tension... Get help from a professional to assess this accurately.

Additionally you could cut open a 12in strip along that corner to expose any other revealing hints at the cause. Be prepared that this might not lead you to the cause and only leave you with a big mess. Patching a ceiling/wall corner can be done but it is not easy for a beginning DIY.

To fix it aesthetically (which I do not recommend at this point, unless you are certain it is just that, an aesthetic problem and not a structural issue), you could cover the corner with crown moulding. Moulding can tolerate small movement better than a drywalled corner.